# Why isn't time axis vertical?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Why isn't time axis vertical? I don't find any reason behind it. This graph is drawn in tree frame. Though the tree isn't moving the time axis isn't vertical. Please help me to understand it.  This picture is captured from this book "An_Illustrated_Guide_to_Relativity" page no:37

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the question? What curve are you talking about? The illustration has time as an independent quantity.

Comment: is it correct now?

Comment: is it correct now?

Comment: It's convention, when you have a variable dependent on another, that the independent variable be placed on the horizontal axis. But it's only a convention, you can of course plot it on the vertical!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection. I think that's the answer to your question; they were trying to draw the graph with a perspective to have the objects appear to "stand up" off the graph.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a drawing convention. Rather than "vertical", time is orthogonal to the x-axis. The reason it is not shown vertical is because the paper surface is 2D, and the author uses the vertical axis for drawing the altitude with respect to the ground. Just recall the way you draw the 3D axis. Here, the author uses X (horizontal),Y (vertical) and time (inwards).

Comment: Sometimes the attempt to make things understandable fails miserably.  :)